# node js can not find caw module

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

i trying push my node application

but it is fail with this error message Error: Cannot find module 'caw'

my local environment works well however cloudfoundry environment don't work

If you have experienced the same problem, please help me.

Comment: check whether `cow` module listed in you package.json, if no then run `npm i  caw --save`

Comment: Please add your package.json file and how you push the app to the question.

Comment: Thanks. 
@styopdev 
i solved this problem.
It was a temporary network failure.

Comment: Thanks. 
@data_henrik 
i solved this problem.
It was a temporary network failure.